# Only show parts of an .ascx template's HTML to administrators (nobody else) using <% %> or equivalent

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm working remotely on a client's DotNetNuke website, extending existing HTML templates. The client has demanded that this new content must be hidden until they have reviewed it.

Is there a way I can hide parts of the template's HTML and only display it to administrators?

I'm ideally looking for something like this:

```
<div>
    <% Admin Only %>
        <p>Only administrators can see this!</p>
    <% End Admin Only %>
    <p>Everyone can see this</p>
</div>
```

(I'm not greatly familiar with ASP.NET so I'm not sure what the <% %> notation is called.)

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a method and call this method using ASP.NET inline expressions as shown below.

IF Language is **VB**

```
<script runat="server">
    Public Function IsUserAdmin() As Boolean
        Dim uinfo As DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo()
        If uinfo.UserID <> -1 Then
            If uinfo.IsInRole(DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings.Current.AdministratorRoleName) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function
</script>
```

and ASP.NET inline expressions is

```
<%  If IsUserAdmin() Then%>
       <p>Only administrators can see this!</p>
    <%  End If%>
```

IF Language is **C#**

```
<script runat="server">
    public bool IsUserAdmin()
    {
        DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo uinfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo();
        if (uinfo.UserID != -1)
        {
            if (uinfo.IsInRole(DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings.Current.AdministratorRoleName))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

and ASP.NET inline expressions is

```
<% if (IsUserAdmin()) %>
    <%
       { %>
       <p>Only administrators can see this!</p>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: This threw an error: `Could Not Load Skin: /Portals/.../index.ascx, Error: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\...\index.ascx(144): error BC30205: End of statement expected.` Line 144 being `public bool IsUserAdmin()`.

Comment: @James what is your Control Language c# or vb

Comment: I'd imagine it should be C# as the company I work on usually uses C# but I'm not entirely sure. Is there a way I can find out without having access to anything other than the .ascx template files?

Comment: Yes definitely you can find in .ascx file, see the top of .ascx file.It will be there like this <%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="WebUserControl" %>

Comment: Ah, it is VB. `language="vb"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, replacing where necessary the code for determining role membership and whether content is reviewed:

```
<div>
    <% if (Page.User.IsInRole("administrator") || objContent.IsReviewed)
     {%>
        <p>Only administrators can see this!</p>
    <% }%>
    <p>Everyone can see this</p>
</div>
```

Actually, DNN is VB right? If so:

```
<div>
    <% If Page.User.IsInRole("administrator") Or objContent.IsReviewed Then%>
        <p>Only administrators can see this!</p>
    <% End If%>
    <p>Everyone can see this</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The C# solution broke the page, so it must be VB. The VB solution didn't change anything - I was still able to see it regardless of whether I was logged in or not.

Comment: Yes, thought it was VB. Are you sure you've logged out and the content is not 'reviewed'? My test app here did hide the administrator-only msg.

Comment: I tried it with just `Page.User.IsInRole("administrator")` and the content still shows up when logged out (and after clearing cookies).